# How to install the USB drivers for ROS

Tags: installation, ros

i already installed the both cheese and gucv application for simple output from usb, but then i had trouble with installing the usbcam packages for ROS.
How can i install the usbcamera packages?

i tried to install the ros-fuerte-camera-umd, but it says that unable to locate that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [Create a ROS workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment)

Then download the package and save it in `your_working_space\src\`

Later go back to `your_working_space` and run `catkin make` it will install the package.